# react.js media queries and carousel

Tags: css, reactjs

Currently working with React.js and to to use media query, unless there is another solution. THis is the link I have been trying to use but does not seem to work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive  .
My component consist of 8 images  with-in a carousel: https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel.
I would like to lay out the images at 4 at 1600px width and 2 images at IPad Width
and 1 image at 480px.  They should not stack. This media query does not work for me with this carousel.   If you know of a solution to accomplish the above please let me know.   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan on incorporating this everywhere in your app I would suggest not including a new library. You can conditionally render elements by pulling information from window.innerWidth. Here's a fiddle I made that should show the basics: https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/w837k9s7/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        width: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWidth.bind(this))
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
  }

  updateWidth(){
    this.setState({width: window.innerWidth});
  }

  render(){
  console.log(this.state.width)
    switch(true){
        case this.state.width<= 480:
        return (<div>This is a Phone</div>)
      case this.state.width<= 768:
        return(<div> This is an iPad</div>)
      default:
        return(<div> This is a computer</div>)
    }
  }
}
```